# Exposing application specific counters via JMX/SNMP

Tags: java, jmx, snmp

Certain real-time features of the server application I'm working on would benefit from exposing counters to a Network Management System.

I am thinking about a solution where I am using the JMX API from a Java application and via some configuration/magic/libraries can expose this information as SNMP data.

Back in the old days, JDMK did something like this I quess. Is that still the best solution? Was there some issues regarding the license of JDMK?

What about MX4J, can it be used to export counters via SNMP?

Other, better solutions?